# Excel VBA - Group Data by Column A, Get the Range Value from C - Copy results to New Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I've been trying to search for an example of this grouping and tested few code snippets but haven't been able to adapt it to what I need as I'm just getting to know Excel vba.
What I'm trying to do is to group by column A then get the range of the values used in that category which are in column C and get the results in a new worksheet.

Main Sheet.

```
A   B           C       D

3   Baseball    4       Blue

2   Football    1       Red

2   Football    3       Red

3   Baseball    4       Blue

1   Soccer      2       Green

3   Baseball    4       Blue

1   Soccer      3       Green

1   Soccer      5       Green

2   Football    2       Red
```

---

Expected Results:

New Sheet.

```
A   B           C       D

1   Soccer      2-5     Green   

2   Football    1-3     Red

3   Baseball    4       Blue
```

Comment: Are columns A,B and D always a one to one relationship?

Comment: This can be done with formulas is vba necessary?

Comment: @ScottCraner: Yes, as described on the main sheet. I can use anything that gets the job done,  however I was thinking to be able to run it as a "Macro" or hit some button to execute the process. thank you for looking into this.

Comment: How many rows in the dataset, more specifically, how many unique rows will be for  A | B | D?

Comment: You could come pretty close to what you want with a Pivot Table

Comment: @ScottHoltzman row number can vary in the dataset. The rows to be grouped can be many as well, there is no specific number.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Yes, I tried that, however I need to process the results to add two more columns, depending on the results. I guess that's why I need vba

Comment: What have you tried?  Where have you run into problems?  With an incomplete description of what you are really trying to do, it is hard to advise. In VBA, you can use the Collection (or Dictionary) objects to generate your unique lists, and then Collect each set of items indexed, for example, by either your first or second column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually figure this out:

```
For Each key In fCatId.Keys
    'Debug.Print fCatId(key), key
    With wshcore
        llastrow = wshcore.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A1:N" & llastrow).AutoFilter
        .Range("A1:N" & llastrow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=fCatId(key)
        lwmin = WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(5, Range("H:H"))
        lwmax = WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(4, Range("H:H"))
```

Im getting column a: fcatid, b: key, lwmin: lowest value and lwmax: highest.

Answer (score 0):

If you need column C to be a range of value, eg `2 - 5`, then it's text in Excel. Pivot table only able to return Min, Max, Sum, Average, but not range of the value.

You will need using VBA to solve the problem.

First, copy column A,B,D to some where, then using Remove Duplicate.
To find out the Unique combination.

Eg: (Assuming you have some new records in future)

```
A   B           C       D

3   Baseball    4       Blue

2   Football    1       Red

2   Football    3       Red

3   Baseball    4       Blue

1   Soccer      2       Green

3   Baseball    4       Blue

1   Soccer      3       Green

1   Soccer      5       Green

2   Football    2       Red 

4   Tennis      3       Yellow
```

Then you should have something like below:

```
A   B           D

1   Soccer      Green   

2   Football    Red

3   Baseball    Blue

4   Tennis      Yellow
```

Then using Loop, to find out the range of the value for each of the Unique Combination (here we have 4 unique records).

*** assume that you know how to use loop to find out the Range of each combination.